# Float Division Calculator

Tags: c, variables, calculator, division

Hey I'm new to learning how to use C programming and I'm having trouble with the division part of a calculator. I need to have it float and have 2 decimal places. I think I need to use %f instead of %d but it breaks when I change the variables. Fans is float answer.

Here's the entire code. The division is Case 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int menu(void);

int main(void){
  int selection, num1, num2, ans;
  float fans;
  selection = menu();
  while (selection !=8) {
    switch (selection) {
        case 1: printf("Enter 1st number: ");
            scanf("%d", &num1);
            printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num2);
                ans = num1 + num2;
                printf("%d + %d = %d\n", num1, num2, ans);
break;
        case 2: printf("Enter 1st number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
                printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num2);
                ans = num1 - num2;
                printf("%d - %d = %d\n", num1, num2, ans);
break;
        case 3: printf("Enter 1st number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
                printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num2);
                ans = num1 * num2;
                printf("%d * %d = %d\n", num1, num2, ans);
break;
    case 4: printf("Enter 1st number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
                printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num2);
            if(num2 != 0) {
            fans=(float)num1/num2;
                printf("%d / %d = %d\n", num1, num2, ans);
            }
            else {
                printf("Error. Cannot divide by 0!\n");
            }
break;
    case 5: printf("Enter number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
                ans=abs(num1);
                printf("|%d| = %d\n", num1, ans);
break;
    case 6: printf("Enter number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
            if(num1<0) {
                printf("Error. Cannot be a negative number.\n");
            }
        else {
                fans=sqrt(num1);
                printf("Sqrt(%d)=%d\n", num1, ans);
            }
break;
    case 7: printf("Enter base number: ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
                printf("Enter exponent: ");
                scanf("%d", &num2);
            if((num1==0)&&(num2<=0)){
               printf("Error. Power cannot be represented.\n");
            }
            else {
               fans=pow(num1,num2);
               printf("%d^%d=%d\n", num1, num2, ans);
            }
break;
       default:printf("%d is not a valid selection\n", selection);
      }
     selection=menu();
    }
   printf("Bye!\n");
  }

int menu(void) {
   int choice;
   printf("1 Add\n");
   printf("2 Subtract\n");
   printf("3 Multiply\n");
   printf("4 Divide\n");
   printf("5 Absolute Value\n");
   printf("6 Square Root\n");
   printf("7 Powers\n");
   printf("8 Quit\n");
   scanf("%d", &choice);
 return choice;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `fans=(float)num1/num2;
                printf("%d / %d = %d\n", num1, num2, ans);` --> `fans=(float)num1/num2;
                printf("%d / %d = %.2f\n", num1, num2, fans);` ?

Comment: A calculator that accepts only integer input is pretty useless. What happens if you want to divide 2.5 by 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close; you meant to use `fans` since you know it's a float answer, and you calculated on the previous line, but typo or forgot to use it.

You're right use `%f`:

```
printf("%d / %d = %f\n", num1, num2, fans);
```

Note: `%.2f` will also work for 2 places precision; `%f` works but prints 6 decimal places.  See the POSIX specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html):

`f` — `double` — prints float with a default precision of 6, if no precision is given; lower-case.

By the way, nice calculator program :)